# HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests on IBM Cloudant with python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cloudant, http-error

IBM Cloudant is connected to Jupyter notebook. I can work with database which is not very big. But when I want to get a data from the database which has many data, I get this error:

HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests too_many_requests You've exceeded your current limit of 5 requests per second for query class. Please try later

Is there anything to do for this problem?
Any idea will be really helpful.

here is my code:

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
from cloudant.error import CloudantException
from cloudant.result import Result, ResultByKey
import cloudant
import pandas as pd
import json

serviceUsername = "x"
servicePassword = "y"
serviceURL = "z"
client = Cloudant(serviceUsername, servicePassword, url=serviceURL)
client.connect()

database1 = client['comfort']
userID= input("what is your user ID?")

for item in database1:
  if userID == 'user_id':
    print(item)
```

and here is what I get

```
what is your user ID?ss


> HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)
>     <ipython-input-7-98e9b2d333f5> in <module>()
>           4 userID= input("what is your user ID?")
>           5 
>     ----> 6 for item in database1:
>           7     if userID == 'user_id':
>           8         print(item)
>     
>     ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cloudant\database.py in __iter__(self, remote)
>         634                                                   # next_startkey
>         635                     include_docs=True,
>     --> 636                     startkey=next_startkey
>         637                 ).get('rows', [])
>         638 
>     
>     ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cloudant\database.py in all_docs(self, **kwargs)
>         391                         '/'.join([self.database_url, '_all_docs']),
>         392                         self.client.encoder,
>     --> 393                         **kwargs)
>         394         return resp.json()
>         395 
>     
>     ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cloudant\_common_util.py in get_docs(r_session, url, encoder, headers, **params)
>         263     else:
>         264         resp = r_session.get(url, headers=headers, params=f_params)
>     --> 265     resp.raise_for_status()
>         266     return resp
>         267 
>     
>     ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in raise_for_status(self)
>         933 
>         934         if http_error_msg:
>     --> 935             raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
>         936 
>         937     def close(self):
>     
>     HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests too_many_requests You've exceeded your current limit of 5 requests per second for query
> class. Please try later. for url:
> https://2b5a4b.......
```

Comment: i've never used this DB but doesn't look as if you're querying it the right way. seems that you're iterating over the whole DB and each scan of a row is a request and Python is sending requests to Cloudant faster than they allow hence the problem. why don't you try using a `join`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure where to use it ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try querying like this:

```
database1 = client['comfort']
userID= input("what is your user ID?")

selector = {'user_id': {'$eq': userID}}
docs = database1.get_query_result(selector)
for doc in docs:
    do stuff...
```

Got this straight from [the docs](http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html)

Comment: It works halfly. I can get the output of only half of data. Before other half, I got this "HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests" error, again.

Comment: sounds like you will need to use pagination here, you could also return all the results as JSON at once if you supply the `raw_results` flag, maybe you should look over the docs more

Comment: Hi again, thank you for helps. it works when I fill the 'get_query_result' with a limit. Like that  " resp = database1.get_query_result(selector1, raw_result=True, limit=2000)"

Answer (score 0):

So, the actual definite answer to this is to add a so-called Replay429Adapter to the connection.

This will take care of catching HTTP429 errors and retrying and pacing the connection to alleviate direct impact of the 5 Query Per Second limit of Cloudant Lite plans on IBM Cloud.
This is actually documented, once you know what to look for:
https://python-cloudant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=Replay429Adapter
You will need to add:

`from cloudant.adapters import Replay429Adapter`

and then, add

      `,adapter=Replay429Adapter(retries=10, initialBackoff=0.01))`

to your Cloudant client connector creation

See also https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant/issues/249

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Replay429Adapter is the correct solution for this error and a real resilient client.

My client connection looks like this (using IAM auth):

```
from cloudant.client import Cloudant
from cloudant.adapters import Replay429Adapter
db_client = Cloudant.iam(cloudant_username, cloudant_apikey, connect=True, adapter=Replay429Adapter(retries=10, initialBackoff=0.01))
```